# Can I apply a filter to items that have already been filtered (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to filter items from a nested array that have already been filtered but I don't want the previous filter to be removed.

I define the array initially like this:

```
markers1 = [
    ['0', '15 Smith Ct', 50.472711, -3.540386, 'Dartington', 'House', 'http://google.com/',
     'https://www.msvhousing.co.uk/images/properties/for-rent/609/khubsuret%20compressed.jpg'],
    ['1', '27 Clobells', 50.424091, -3.832449, 'Dartington', 'Bungalow', 'http://google.com',
     'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480074568708-e7b720bb3f09?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80'],
    ['2', '155 Churchill Rd', 51.011143, -4.195814, 'Bideford', 'Flat', 'http://google.com',
     'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449844908441-8829872d2607?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80'],
    ['3', 'Dennis Camp Rd', 50.431930, -4.121285, 'Plymouth', 'Bungalow', 'http://google.com',
     'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552903023-dc7b4c9fa5bf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60']
];
```

Then the content is assigned like this:

```
function addMarker(marker) {
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var location = marker[4];
    var property = marker[5];
    var link = marker[6];
    var image = marker[7]

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        location: location,
        map: map,
        property: property,
        link: link,
        image: image
    });
```

Then my filter works like so:

```
filterMarkers = function (location) {
    // clear div x
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = " ";
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same location or location not picked
        if (marker.location == location || location.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById('x').innerHTML += "<div class='col-sm col-md-4 mt-5 mt-lg-0'><img class='w-100 mt-5' src=" + marker.image + " style='max-height:200px' ><br><div class='display-6 my-3 ml-3'>" 
            + marker.title + "</div><a class='lead ml-3' href='" + marker.link + "'>View more about this property</a></div>";
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // locations don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And then there's another which works exactly the same but on a different part of the array.

So this filters the locations (Dartington, Bideford and Plymouth) which is fine. But once this is done I want to now filter the types of houses in, let's say, Dartington so that only houses in Dartington will be output.

Hopefully this makes sense, if it doesn't please let me know and if this has already been answered elsewhere I could not find it so I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Arrays have a built-in `.filter()` function that will return a new array containing only the elements that passed the filter. If you use that, the answer for applying the second filter is, just filter the previously filtered array instead of the original. At the moment you're not really filtering, you're looping and just hiding what does not apply. So the 'easiest' solution for your current code, is just saving the previous filter somewhere and apply all the filters again each time.

Comment: @Shilly ahh okay, that make a lot of sense! Thank you very much!
Going on from my current solution,  how would it be possible to remove the hidden items if the user desired so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just showing the principle. Didn't bother with connecting it to actual google maps, but that can stay the same.

```js
// collection of markers
var marker_collection = [
  [ '0','15 Smith Ct', 50.472711, -3.540386, 'Dartington', 'House', 'http://google.com', 'https://www.msvhousing.co.uk/images/properties/for-rent/609/khubsuret%20compressed.jpg' ],
  ['1', '27 Clobells', 50.424091, -3.832449, 'Dartington', 'Bungalow', 'http://google.com',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480074568708-e7b720bb3f09?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80'],
  ['2', '155 Churchill Rd', 51.011143, -4.195814, 'Bideford', 'Flat', 'http://google.com',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449844908441-8829872d2607?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80'],
  ['3', 'Dennis Camp Rd', 50.431930, -4.121285, 'Plymouth', 'Bungalow', 'http://google.com',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552903023-dc7b4c9fa5bf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60']
];
// Inititally we start with all the markers, so we clone the full collection.
// Just use an empty array if you want to start with nothing.
// Since the inner arrays only contain strings and numbers, we can just slice those.
var clone_array = function( array ) {
  return array.map(function( marker ) {
    return marker.slice();
  });
};
var selected_markers = clone_array( marker_collection );
// Separate reusable function to render all makers.
// We will only use the selected_markers from now on for rendering
// And the marker_collection to reset back to everything.
var render = function( markers ) {
  var html = markers.map(function( marker ) {
    // Usign the array since we didn't create google maps objects.
    var image = marker[7];
    var title = marker[1];
    var link = marker[6];
    // var { image, title, link } = marker;
    return `<div class='col-sm col-md-4 mt-5 mt-lg-0'><img class='w-100 mt-5' src="${ image }" style='max-height:200px' ><br><div class='display-6 my-3 ml-3'>"${ title }"</div><a class='lead ml-3' href='"${ link }"'>View more about this property</a></div><button`; 
  });
  document.querySelector( 'main' ).innerHTML = html.join( '' );
};
// Add a filter function some way.
// Just using a button and a fixed location as an example.
// You'd get the location from whatever the user selected.
var filter = function( event ) {
  var location = 'Dartington';
  // filter the markers
  // When the markers are gogole objects instead of arrays, you'll use marker.location again instead of marker[4]
  var remaining_markers = selected_markers.filter(function( marker ) {
    return marker[4] === location;
  });
  // save the remaining markers so we can filter those again if needed.
  selected_markers = remaining_markers;
  // after filtering, rerender the remaining markers.
  render( selected_markers );
};
// add the filter event to the button
document.querySelector( '#filter' ).addEventListener( 'click', filter );
// reset the markers back to the original
// So we just do the same as before, clone the original array and then rerender.
var reset = function( event ) {
  selected_markers = clone_array( marker_collection );
  render( selected_markers );
};
// add the reset event to the button
document.querySelector( '#reset' ).addEventListener( 'click', reset );
// initial render upon startup
render( selected_markers );
```

```html
<button id="filter">Filter</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<main></main>
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you! With regard to the line "var location = 'Dartington';" how would I change it so that the user can select the location themselves which would then filter the location? Previously I was using <select> and <option value="Dartington"> etc. in order to jump between the options. With your code, my idea was to use <select> again and in place of the line I referenced at the start, replace Dartington with getElementById() but that didn't work for me. Could you suggest a method to do this?

Comment: That should just be `var location = document.querySelector( '#IDofTheSelect' ).value;`. The nice thing is that you can then just use an onchange event on the <select> to call filter().

Comment: Sorted me out again, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

`The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.` More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Thus, you can apply as many filters as you want.

You can also chain them like this:

```
const resultArray = array.filter(filterFunction1).filter(filterFunction2)
```

This will apply the filters in the sequence you've defined.